# C++ send data to Webserver

Tags: c++, http, post, webserver, libcurl

Currenlty i am trying to send data to a webserver using c++
Right now im using libcurl, but i am facing problem with it, as its slow.

I am kinda new with c++, so I was wondering what other alternatives are available to send data to a webpage, which in turn stores them to database.

I have something likes this now

```
sprintf(data, "&val1=&val2=&val3=&val4.....",val1, val2, val3, val4....);
then send this data using curl post
```

the problem is that, the val1,val2,val3,val4 is actually being grabbed from a program, which actually generates 2 sample values per second, hence the curl function becomes slow. 
So can someone please help me with any better alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

If you must for the sake of speed, you can always try to open a socket with the webserver and directly transmit a self-generated POST message over TCP/IP.  That being said, you'll still have to wait for the proper hand-shake as well as a response from the server in the TCP/IP transmission state, thus the perceived "slowness" of the connection may not be something under your control.

For speed, generally UDP is preferred over TCP/IP due it's lack of checking for a response and other packet-transmission guarantees. In this case though, you may have to buffer the values coming in from your source before you attempt to send them to the webserver, with the hopes that you won't eventually run out of buffer space.

Comment: could u guide me on any examples of TCP/IP communication with a webserver?

Comment: You basically need to format a string (ASCII) so that it conforms to the HTTP POST request format.  You send the formatted POST request to port 80 on the webserver by calling `write()` on the socket you've opened on your side (i.e., look at the documentation for `socket()` in Linux), and it will then generate a HTTP response back to you that you'll get by calling `read()` on the socket.  There is some great information [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). You'll need to make sure you don't forget the `cr` and `lf` characters at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

It's not curl that becomes slow, it's the fact that you're inducing a very slow process too frequently.

Buffer more of your data before sending it. Send it in larger chunks. Look into a technique called double-buffering so you don't miss any updates.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering